# Выполнение потенциально долгого php-скрипта, запущенного через cron

Tags: php, cron

Скажу сразу, я не php-программист, но есть потребность в исполнении потенциально долгого скрипта (php) на виртуальном хостинге. Задача связана с обновлением [потенциально] большого числа записей в б/д. Для этого планирую создать cron-задание. В связи с этим такой вопрос: верно ли я понимаю, что скрипты, запускаемые с помощью штук типа cron не имеют ограничений по времени исполнения и памяти (за исключением относительно больших физических лимитов на память и процессорное время, установленных хостером для моего тарифа)? То есть не получится ли так, что скрипт проработает, например, минут 5, а потом тихо порушится, не закончив начатое? Существует ли гарантия, что скрипт отработает до конца и завершится корректно, пусть даже он будет шуршать медленно в фоновом режиме? И вообще, я иду в верном направлении в плане связки php-cron для озвученной выше задачи?

Comment: Насколько я помню, есть лимит по памяти. Для таких задач его надо увеличивать (если есть возможность конечно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> верно ли я понимаю, что скрипты, запускаемые с помощью штук типа cron не имеют ограничений по времени исполнения

верно

> и памяти

неверно

> Существует ли гарантия, что скрипт отработает до конца и завершится корректно

Гарантию дает только Господь бог. Это странный вопрос, который, *разумеется*, не может иметь положительного ответа.
Если речь только про вылет по времени выполнения, то да, гарантия есть. Но остальные причины вылета, от ошибок в скрипте до перезагрузки сервера никто не отменял.
Или, например, скрипт шуршит так долго, что следующий запуск по крону запускает вторую копию, которая ломает результаты работы первой.

> я иду в верном направлении в плане связки php-cron для озвученной выше задачи

Ну, если нужно гарантировать непрерывную работу сервиса, то можно замутить самопального демона, типа шелл скрипта, который запускает команду в цикле. Но это зависит от задачи. Про которую, кстати сказать, в вопросе нет ни слова.

Comment: да, я имел в виду именно гарантию от вылета по времени выполнения. Про задачу я написал - обновлять б/д новыми данными со стороннего сервиса.

Answer (score 3):

в описанных двух вариантах запуска интерпретатора *php* — из *http*-сервера и из командной строки (== «из cron-задания»), как правило, используются разные файлы конфигурации (`php.ini`). и, соответственно, интерпретатор может получить совершенно разные конфигурационные параметры.

вы можете посмотреть эти параметры с помощью *php*-функции `phpinfo()` (в начале вывода, кстати, будет присутствовать и путь к используемому `php.ini`):

1. вызов из *http*-сервера: создайте в *docroot*-е сайта файл с произвольным именем и суффиксом `.php` (например, `info.php`) следующего содержания:

   ```
   <?php phpinfo();
   ```

   и обратитесь к нему из *http*-браузера — `http://ваш.сайт/info.php`
2. вызов из командной строки:

   ```
   $ php -r 'phpinfo();'
   ```

   или даже короче:

   ```
   $ php -i
   ```

при сравнении обратите внимание на интересующие вас конфигурационные параметры: `max_execution_time` и `memory_limit`.

если вас не устраивают какие-либо конфигурационные параметры, то при запуске из командной строки вы можете их переопределить с помощью опции `-d`:

```
$ php -d 'параметр=значение' ...
```

либо, ещё радикальнее, создав собственный `php.ini` с нужными параметрами, и указав использовать именно его:

```
$ php -c /путь/к/вашему/php.ini ...
```

Comment: Автор, не нужно читать это развесистое послание абсолютно ни о чем.

Comment: @Ипатьев, конечно, было бы интересно узнать, что именно вас не устроило в моём ответе, но, надеюсь, что вы напишете хотя бы свой, *правильный*, ответ.

Comment: сообщение нормальное, всё ок :) В php.ini, используемом на http-сервере max_execution_time = 30 и memory_limit = 128М. Из ваших ответов я понял, что если запускать скрипт cron-ом, то время исполнения будет столько, сколько надо для скрипта. Насчет памяти - предполагается выборка записей б/д и прогон их в цикле с обновлением 1 поля для каждой записи. Как я понимаю, в php подобная операция асинхронна, то есть возвращаемые записи попадают из б/д в память и обрабатываются по мере поступления, а не хранятся все сразу в памяти.

Comment: По идее как минимум 128М должно хватить при условии, что скрипт может работать столько, сколько ему надо? Поправьте, пожалуйста, если я не прав.

Comment: @curveball, сколько может потребоваться памяти — сложно предположить. я думаю, имеет смысл вообще не ограничивать размер памяти при запуске из командной строки (запуск из крон-задания с точки зрения php-параметров ничем не отличается). скорее всего, в вашей системе так и есть — запустите `php -i` и убедитесь.